# Parse CloudCode function not working. I get an error when calling it

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, cloud

The CloudCode function is:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('addFriend', function(request, response) {
   var userId = request.params.userId;

   var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
       user = new User({ objectId: userId });

   var currentUser = request.user;

   var relation = user.relation("Friends");
   relation.add(currentUser);

   Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
   user.save().then(function(user) {
       response.success(user);
   }, function(error) {
    response.error(error)
   });
});
```

When I call it from Xcode with PFCloud call.... I get the next error in my console:

```
[Error]: ReferenceError: parent is not defined
at e.n.value (Parse.js:13:7510)
at main.js:10:14 (Code: 141, Version: 1.8.2)
```

This means the actual problem is that the relation has no parent. It should already have the 'user' variable as a parent because I'm calling user.relation("Friends") , that's what the docs are saying : "You rarely should set manually the parent because as you are most probably going to call Parse.Object.relation('key')." which is what I am doing.

UPDATE

Even this code is giving the same error :

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("addFriend", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var currentUser = request.user;
    var relation = currentUser.relation("Friends");
    relation.add(currentUser);
});
```

UPDATE 2:

User JSON

```
{
   "FriendRequests": {
    "__type": "Relation",
    "className": "_User"
},
   "Friends": {
    "__type": "R‌​elation",
    "className": "_User"
},
"createdAt": {
    "__type": "Date",
    "iso": "2015-09-10T17:29‌​:03.181Z"
},
"sessionToken": "r:KkmTu7xRjTEFpl0vcANVf0xXH",
"updatedAt": {
   "__type": "Dat‌​e",
   "iso": "2015-09-10T17:29:03.181Z"
 },
 "username": "bogdan12",
 "objectId": "BmbNRxCyau‌​"
```

}

Relation JSON

```
{
    "__type": "Relation",
    "className": "_User"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing :

```
var User = Parse.Object.extend('_User'),
    user = new User({ objectId: userId });
```

With :

```
    user = new Parse.User.createWithoutData(userId);
```

**EDIT :**

It works fine with me... Here is what I tried :

Cloud :

```
Parse.Cloud.define('addFriend', function(request, response)
{
    var currentUser = request.user;
    var userId = request.params.userId;
    var user = new Parse.User.createWithoutData(userId);

    var relation = user.relation("Friends");
    relation.add(currentUser);

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    user.save().then(function(user) {
        response.success(user);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error)
    });
});
```

Client :

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"addFriend" withParameters:@{@"userId":@"s8BMHtnqSZ"} block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
    if (!object || error) {
        LogError(error, @"Calling addFriend failed.");
    } else {
        LogInfo(@"Calling addFriend succeeded.");
    }
}];
```

Maybe you should file a bug report here : https://www.parse.com/help

Comment: It's possible that you need to fetch the user first before editing the relation.

Comment: Look at the update... Is it a Parse.Relation bug maybe?

Comment: Can you log the content of currentUser and relation (using toJSON()) and tell me which line the error is ?

Comment: E2015-09-13T15:56:01.819Z]v55 Ran cloud function editUser for user BmbNRxCyau with:
  Input: {"userId":"14xJE7rFOQ"}
  Result: ReferenceError: parent is not defined
    at e.n.value (Parse.js:13:7510)
    at main.js:10:14

Comment: This is the error. The JSON are in Update 2 in question.

Comment: Could you write a similar function and run it? And test if it works? It's really weird...

Comment: Copy pasted your function , called it like you called it...everything is just right... I get this:   TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: Ah I think you just found the bug ! I was using 1.5.0, which works fine. With 1.6.0 I have this bug too. You should report it, it definitely looks like a bug from Parse. In the mean time you can use 1.5.0

Comment: Well actually check the changelog here first : https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads It might not be a bug but a very discreet, very secret, very under the radar, very without telling anyone not backward compatible update...

Comment: Yes, you're right...finally... thanks! It's already reported: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1677477152487599/

Comment: `cd` into your cloud code directory and run `parse jssdk 1.5.0` and `parse deploy`. If you're on windows it might be different, check here : https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#command-line